# Mongoose populate many objects using 'path array' {path: objectpath,model:'Model'}

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate

In my webapp, after ordering (SingleOrder) for products, the customer should check for offers. if available, then I should add the order to the ComboOfferOrder.

There, I want to check for the order's payment status. Also, I have to get the entire products list.

I have all the values in my db in backend. But I am not able to populate any of the objects in 'SingleOrder' for my api method.

I have the below schemas.

```
*User*    
{
name : String,
email : Sring,
role : String
}

*BankTransaction*
{
    type : String,
    transationReference: String,
    date : Date,
    amount : Number
}


*ComboOfferOrder*  
 {
   customer :{
    type :Schema.ObjectId,
    ref : 'User'
    },
    order : {
    type :Schema.ObjectId,
    ref : 'SingleOrder'
    },
    productList : [{
    type :Schema.ObjectId,
    ref : 'Product'
    }]
    discount : Number,
    totalCost : Number,
    paymentStatus :String,
    deliveryStatus : String

  }




    *SingleOrder*
        {    
        code: String,
        products : {
          groceries:[{
              type :Schema.ObjectId,
              ref : 'Product'
          }],
          other:[{
              type :Schema.ObjectId,
              ref : 'Product'
          }]   
        },
        billingAddress: String,
        deliveryAddress : String,
        payment:{
         status : String,
         transaction :{
            type :Schema.ObjectId,
            ref : 'BankTransaction'
         }
       }   
      }

    *Products*
    {
    name : String,
    cost : Number,
    expiryDate : Date
    }
```

**My api**

```
mongoose.model('ComboOfferOrder')
            .findOne({
                _id: comboOfferOrderId
            })
            .select('order')          
            .exec(function(err, comboOfferOrder) {
                var paths = [
                    {path : "payment.status"},
                    {path : "payment.trasaction"},
                    {path : "products.groceries"},
                    {path : "products.other"}                    
                ];
                mongoose.model('comboOfferOrder').populate(comboOfferOrder.order,paths,function(err, singleOrder) {                   
                    if (err) {
                        return deferred.reject(err);
                    }
                    return deferred.resolve(comboOfferOrder.order);
                });
            });
```

In the result, I get only the objectIds of "payment.status","payment.trasaction",products.groceries",   "products.other"

Please let me know the solution.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** populate a nested field with mongoose, and therefore you must nest your callbacks.

You may reread the documentation of [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-populate) for usage examples.

This should work (not tested):

```
mongoose.model('ComboOfferOrder')
.findOne({
    _id: comboOfferOrderId
})
.select('order')          
.exec(function(err, comboOfferOrder) {
    comboOfferOrder.populate('order', function(err, singleOrder) {                   
        singleOrder.populate('products.other products.groceries etc...', function(err, singleOrder) {
            if (err) {
                return deferred.reject(err);
            }
            return deferred.resolve(singleOrder);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Populate lets you get a list of a user's friends, but what if you also wanted a user's friends of friends? Specify the populate option to tell mongoose to populate the friends array of all the user's friends:

```
User.
findOne({ name: 'Val' }).
populate({
path: 'friends',
// Get friends of friends - populate the 'friends' array for every friend
populate: { path: 'friends' }
});
```